# Download an already uploaded Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a lambda function in AWS (Python) using "upload .zip"
I lost those files and I need to make some changes, is there is any way to download that .zip?

Answer (score 534, accepted):

**Yes!**

Navigate over to your lambda function settings and on the top right you will have a button called "`Actions`". In the drop down menu select "`export`" and in the popup click "Download deployment package" and the function will download in a `.zip` file.

*Action button on top-right*

[image: Step#1]

*A popup from CTA above (Tap "Download deployment package" here)*

[image: Step#2]

Comment: Click on the function. When you are in the functions management page click actions.

Comment: @kit Yes! In the output of the command you should see `code` in there you should find `location`. This is a presigned URL that you can use to download the function. The URL will be valid for 10 minutes.

Comment: @kit
Did you find a way to download the zip using CLI? I have no luck with wget or even curl

Comment: @Vineeth- Yes you can make use of command like: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX aws s3 cp s3://my-images/dev . --recursive

Comment: Worked for me. Just a note that the file I downloaded did not have a `.zip` extension so was just a plain file in Windows. The solution is to manually add the extension to the file name after downloading.

Comment: I don't have an "Export function" button. Perhaps because my function is a container image. Need to know how to download a container image function.

Comment: @foobarbecue it seems the AWS UI is updated, look at my answer, it might have help

Answer (score 49):

Update: Added link to script by [sambhaji-sawant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6908140/sambhaji-sawant). Fixed Typos, improved answer and script based on comments!

You can use [aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest) to download the zip of any lambda.

First you need to get the URL to the lambda zip
`$ aws lambda get-function --function-name $functionName --query 'Code.Location'`

Then you need to use wget/curl to download the zip from the URL.
`$ wget -O myfunction.zip URL_from_step_1`

Additionally you can list all functions on your AWS account using

`$ aws lambda list-functions`

I made a simple bash script to parallel download all the lambda functions from your AWS account. You can see it 
[here](https://gist.github.com/nemaniarjun/defdde356b6678352bcd4af69b7fe529) :)

Note: You will need to setup aws-cli before using the above commands (or any aws-cli command) using `aws configure`

[Full guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

Comment: aws lambda get-function returns a JSON description of the function. To get the actual zip, you need to use the Code.Location attribute with curl or some other HTTP client.

Comment: New link is at the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159281/2506135

Comment: This does not work, even though I am using a profile with credentials, it returns: Connecting to awslambda-us-west-2-tasks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com (awslambda-us-west-2-tasks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com)|52.218.152.33|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-10-20 15:40:30 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: `aws lambda get-function --function-name $functionName --query 'Code.Location'` returns the url enclosed in double quotes, they need to be removed before using `wget`. To remove the quotes you can add the option `--output text`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a bash script that I used, it downloads all the functions in the default region:

```
download_code () {
    local OUTPUT=$1
    OUTPUT=`sed -e 's/,$//' -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//g'  <<<"$OUTPUT"`
    url=$(aws lambda get-function --function-name get-marvel-movies-from-opensearch --query 'Code.Location' )
    wget $url -O $OUTPUT.zip
}

FUNCTION_LIST=$(aws lambda list-functions --query Functions[*].FunctionName)
for run in $FUNCTION_LIST
do
    download_code $run
done

echo "Finished!!!!"
```

Comment: We can add a `grep` and  download functions with common pattern.`FUNCTION_LIST=$(aws lambda list-functions --query Functions[*].FunctionName | grep <pattern>)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download all the functions in the given region here is my workaround.
I have created a simple node script to download function. Install all the required npm packages and set your AWS CLI to the region you want before running the script.

```
let download = require('download-file');
let extract = require('extract-zip');
let cmd = require('node-cmd');

let downloadFile = async function (dir, filename, url) {
    let options = {
        directory: dir,
        filename: filename
    }
    return new Promise((success, failure) => {
        download(url, options, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                failure(err)
            } else {
                success('done');
            }
        })
    })
}

let extractZip = async function (source, target) {
    return new Promise((success, failure) => {
        extract(source, { dir: target }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                failure(err)
            } else {
                success('done');
            }
        })
    })
}

let getAllFunctionList = async function () {
    return new Promise((success, failure) => {
        cmd.get(
            'aws lambda list-functions',
            function (err, data, stderr) {
                if (err || stderr) {
                    failure(err || stderr)
                } else {
                    success(data)
                }
            }
        );
    })
}

let getFunctionDescription = async function (name) {
    return new Promise((success, failure) => {
        cmd.get(
            `aws lambda get-function --function-name ${name}`,
            function (err, data, stderr) {
                if (err || stderr) {
                    failure(err || stderr)
                } else {
                    success(data)
                }
            }
        );
    })
}

let init = async function () {
    try {
        let { Functions: getAllFunctionListResult } = JSON.parse(await getAllFunctionList());
        let getFunctionDescriptionResult, downloadFileResult, extractZipResult;
        getAllFunctionListResult.map(async (f) => {
            var { Code: { Location: getFunctionDescriptionResult } } = JSON.parse(await getFunctionDescription(f.FunctionName));
            downloadFileResult = await downloadFile('./functions', `${f.FunctionName}.zip`, getFunctionDescriptionResult)
            extractZipResult = await extractZip(`./functions/${f.FunctionName}.zip`, `/Users/malhar/Desktop/get-lambda-functions/final/${f.FunctionName}`)
            console.log('done', f.FunctionName);
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }
}


init()
```

Comment: What do **Functions** do in  `let { Functions: getAllFunctionListResult } = JSON.parse(await getAllFunctionList());` in this line

Comment: it's object destructuring creating new variable getAllFunctionListResult and assigning Functions property of JSON.parse to it

Comment: How does it handle the versioning that Lambda provides?  Does this only download $LATEST ?

Answer (score 3):

You can find a python script to download all the lambda functions [here](https://github.com/gantir/handyman/blob/main/aws/download_lambda_functions.py).

```
import os
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

import boto3

def get_lambda_functions_code_url():

client = boto3.client("lambda")

lambda_functions = [n["FunctionName"] for n in client.list_functions()["Functions"]]

functions_code_url = []

for fn_name in lambda_functions:
    fn_code = client.get_function(FunctionName=fn_name)["Code"]
    fn_code["FunctionName"] = fn_name
    functions_code_url.append(fn_code)

return functions_code_url


def download_lambda_function_code(fn_name, fn_code_link, dir_path):

    function_path = os.path.join(dir_path, fn_name)
    if not os.path.exists(function_path):
        os.mkdir(function_path)

    with urlopen(fn_code_link) as lambda_extract:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(lambda_extract.read())) as zfile:
            zfile.extractall(function_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp = sys.argv[1:]
    print("Destination folder {}".format(inp))
    if inp and os.path.exists(inp[0]):
        dest = os.path.abspath(inp[0])
        fc = get_lambda_functions_code_url()
        print("There are {} lambda functions".format(len(fc)))
        for i, f in enumerate(fc):
            print("Downloading Lambda function {} {}".format(i+1, f["FunctionName"]))
            download_lambda_function_code(f["FunctionName"], f["Location"], dest)
    else:
        print("Destination folder doesn't exist")
```

Comment: How am I supposed to run this from a Mac Terminal ? Should I add aws credentials to this code ? Or is this a glue job ?

Comment: @mensch - You can run it after you have installed Python and also installed the Boto3 package: ```pip install boto3```.  On you Mac, you also need to get either temporary credentials that give you read access to Lambda or you must [setup the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) with ```aws configure```.  Then, when you run the program, you pass in a folder name to store the code, like this:
    ```mkdir mycode; python python download_lambda_code.py mycode```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have "Export function options, but I do have "Download function":

[image: Dowanload function]

It is possible to download the function by using this option, the only thing you should consider is that it will download multiple files and the web browser might block the last file which is the function file.