# Recover code deployed through zappa

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask-ask

I deployed my flask-ask application one month ago using zappa. I used the end-points in the alexa skill app. Now I want to modify some of the code which I do not have locally. I need to pull back from the zappa lib. 
I googled but cant find a way to get code back into system .

Answer (score 1):

If the code was deployed to AWS Lambda then you can export the code from Lambda. You can do this using the [AWS console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205890/download-an-already-uploaded-lambda-function) or the awscli (via `aws lambda get-function`).