# How to get the bucket name a lambda is currently pointing to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

This looks like it should be fairly straigth-forward , but I am having a hard time to get the bucket name that a lambda is pointing to form the AWS console.

Lets assume someone created a lambda and set the source to s3 bundle after he/she sets the s3 bucket for the lambda. The name of the bucket the lambda is attached is seems hard to find: [image]

Above is what I get for the lambda, I would expect the current s3 bucket the lambda  is pointed to, but this is not the case.

Am I doing something wrong here, Is there a way to find out what s3 bucket a lambda is sourced to in AWS console?

Answer (score 2):

What you have selected in the screenshot is a direct upload to the Lambda service, which doesn't use S3 (at least not in any way that is visible to you). If you click the dropdown you will see the option to import a zip file from S3. If you select that option it will ask you where you have placed the zip file in S3. Lambda doesn't "point to" an S3 bucket. Each time you upload a zip file you could use a different S3 bucket if you wanted to. It doesn't tie the bucket to the Lambda function and require you to continue using that bucket for subsequent uploads.

Comment: got it , is there a way to get the zip file that was uploaded the last time (through s3 or directly)

Comment: @Snedden27 yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205890/download-an-already-uploaded-lambda-function

Answer (score 1):

You don't tie S3 Bucket to lambda. You tie the zip file that you want lambda to execute.

S3 bucket is just a convenient location to upload your zip file and Lambda setup environment is integrated with S3 so you can point it to the S3 location.

If you delete your zip file after setting up lambda, your lambda will still continue to work as expected. This is because setup environment makes a copy of you zip file and puts it somewhere on S3 in your account which is not visible to you.

If you go back to lambda function after setting it up, you will not see which S3 location the file was uploaded from.