# Download AWS Lambda source package as Zip from AWS CLI

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I want to download AWS Lambda source package as Zip. I know that there is an option to download lambda function as SAM file or deployment package in lambda console. But I don't have access to AWS console in the production environment.
See the attached screens.

[image]

Below are the two available options.

[image]
I want to do same functionality in AWS CLI with minimum shell script commands. After downloading the lambda source in zip format, I will create lambda function in production environment via AWS CLI.

```
aws lambda create-function --region [AWSREGION] --function-name [FUNCTION] --zip-file fileb://[ZIPFILE] --role [ROLEARN] --handler [FILENAME].lambda_handler  --description="[FUNCTIONDESCRIPTION]"  --runtime [RUNTIME] --timeout [TIMEOUT] --memory-size [MEMORYSIZE] --profile [PROFILENAME]
```

Please help me with this matter, help in linux shell script commands will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the answer here :

[Download an already uploaded Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205890/download-an-already-uploaded-lambda-function)

A simple bash solution is also provided at https://gist.github.com/nemaniarjun/defdde356b6678352bcd4af69b7fe529

```
# Parallelly download all aws-lambda functions 
# Assumes you have ran `aws configure` and have output-mode as "text"
# Works with "aws-cli/1.16.72 Python/3.6.7 Linux/4.15.0-42-generic botocore/1.12.62"
download_code () {
    local OUTPUT=$1
    aws lambda get-function --function-name $OUTPUT | head -n 1 | cut -f 2 | xargs wget -O ./lambda_functions/$OUTPUT.zip  
}

mkdir lambda_functions
for run in $(aws lambda list-functions | cut -f 6 | xargs);
doth
    download_code "$run" &
done
```

**Edit**: 
  Credits to the original author. Just sharing the code since the URL may get unreachable later.

Answer (score 5):

bash one liner

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name function_name --query 'Code.Location'  | xargs wget -o function_name.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple Bash script based off the original Python script shared earlier.

The difference being that it accepts JSON input and downloads the files in sequence rather than in parallel.

[AWS Lambda Download Bash Script](https://gist.github.com/reegz/96d552b348fd5f8f4d7bfc3556e9ca98)

```
# !/bin/sh
## List the names of all Lambda functions. Can be constrained by using --max-items
for i in `aws lambda list-functions | grep FunctionName | cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -d '"' -f2`
do
  echo 'Fetching code for function:' $i
  ## Using each name, get the function details and then download the zip file containing the source code.
  aws lambda get-function --function-name $i | grep Location | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | xargs wget -O $i.zip
  echo 'Code downloaded to' $i.zip
done
```

Comment: if you don't have wget, just use curl in the above

`aws lambda get-function --function-name $i | grep Location | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | xargs curl --output $i.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirements you can use `aws lambda get-function` CLI command to download lambda function deployment package.

See Synopsis.

```
  get-function
--function-name <value>
[--qualifier <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

[You can also see full detail.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html)

But this command will not give you the zip file. If you execute the command.

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name MyLambdaFunction
```

It will give you similar to below result.

```
{
    "Code": {
        "RepositoryType": "S3",
        "Location": "https://awslambda-eu-west-1-tasks.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/snapshots/014747066885/MyLambdaFunction-aa227fd0-4d4a-4690-9447-6e1818aaa752?versionId=HoQu5vbudzRpYLe0laIVQIahVN2NVxET&X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEIr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDB%2FdpZU6fCyQG%2ByhJyK3A7Dycy5L9hVWmExELuh6f0jFskmKJ62GhGf3J7LC94wB5E5CU2jplsLhw%2Fd%2FmmmJktzo07wI3XLWvSj6zxbHvJFdscCAqF7AYZOhRQR4mOIN6HkanRrHMBHeoTeDqOT6Yk8elhQYfno7dSHP%2FwdNVutS9P0SNmDLDhrxNLAxceDz8nBj1N9AZqhfMwV65OCtTubgLaLSFei75DosXIUaylWsrXgrz4B%2F6bo8LmeDxhNcYefGOBMvwKtyFSdPAP1TulcJpwQIUIC3losjtcTnRt9CSTxhn7TPMDfw4QI5ITKvxgNzO5T2TF2cJVqbotFFVdqPQNHuL2XLMNU24BwjSwF%2FsKWlV6tygXhdQWpTrJFRW%2FqxV%2BX2C1yq0sjpWtc5SerkrmqHvvDjA0L7GlOpG8Q1BLHyQWj0FPmuhrrPyjyFCNqVkpo6eUl35yK%2BHWa1hsXoEPyccoqdHa4gU%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20190203T092717Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA54NGUQSHZ4CZTFNT%2F20190203%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=ee3bbef557cff32f86d26abc769b14"
    },
    "Configuration": {
        "TracingConfig": {
            "Mode": "PassThrough"
        },
        "Version": "$LATEST",
        "CodeSha256": "l6q5ldtk0YEhEv3wnJhhCiAPyRd2XB1/8nT+ZWk=",
        "FunctionName": "MyLambdaFunction",
        "MemorySize": 3008,
        "RevisionId": "a3bdbef4-8616-4c6a-ba19-074acb80b143",
        "CodeSize": 6083880,
        "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:014747066885:function:MyLambdaFunction",
        "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::014747066885:role/lambda_admin",
        "Timeout": 900,
        "LastModified": "2019-01-30T10:09:50.283+0000",
        "Runtime": "python3.6",
        "Description": "Test MyLambdaFunction"
    }
}
```

Now you need to convert it to zip format file with further tweaks.

You can use below two commands to get a lambda function in zip file format.

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name MyLambdaFunction --profile [AWS_ROFILE] | grep "Location" | awk -F ": " '{ print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' > ~/MyLambdaFunction.txt
wget -i ~/MyLambdaFunction.txt -O ~/MyLambdaFunction.zip
```

Here is a full shell script commands.

```
FUNCTION_NAME=${1}
AWS_PROFILE=[AWSPROFILE]
aws lambda get-function --function-name ${FUNCTION_NAME} --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | grep "Location" | awk -F ": " '{ print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' > ~/${FUNCTION_NAME}.txt
wget -i ~/${FUNCTION_NAME}.txt -O ~/${FUNCTION_NAME}.zip
```

You can convert it to a shell script (e.g getLambdaFunction.sh) and execute it with below command.

```
./getLambdaFunction.sh [FUNCTIONNAME]
```

After getting lambda package as zip file, you can create lambda function.

```
aws lambda create-function --region us-east-1 --function-name MyLambdaFunction --zip-file fileb://MyLambdaFunction.zip --role arn:aws:iam::[AWSACCOUNT]:role/service-role/[LAMBDAROLE] --handler lambda_function.lambda_handler --description="My Lambda Function" --runtime "python3.6" --profile [AWSPROFILE]
```

As a sample: it is assumed that MyLambdaFunction is lambda function name, us-east-1 is aws region and run-time is python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

#### If the chosen answer didn't work for you too, try this:

**Install jq:**

```
# for e.g on a Debian based distro (ubuntu, mint, MXlinux, ..)
sudo apt install jq
```

**Use this script**
(past it in a a file named `download_all_lambda_functions.sh` then run `bash download_all_lambda_functions.sh`)

```bash
download_code () {
    # clean double quotes if found
    local OUTPUT=${1//\"/}
    local dest=./lambda_functions/$OUTPUT.zip
    local URL=$(aws lambda get-function --function-name $OUTPUT --query 'Code.Location')

    # Using curl instead of wget
    echo $URL | xargs curl -o $dest
}

mkdir -p lambda_functions

for run in $(aws lambda list-functions | jq -r .Functions[].FunctionName);
do
    echo Found lambda function: $run
    download_code "$run" 
done

echo "Completed Downloading all the Lamdba Functions!"
```

I believe the chosen answer's code got broken because AWS CLI is returning a JSON file, which is better explored using tools like `jq`

Find gist [here](https://gist.github.com/MossabDiae/845b60f65eea91d8a2acc19e56cff7ee)