# How to find current jar S3 location in AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

Before I upload new jar, I want to find current s3 location so that I can keep it as back up in case I need to revert.
I don't find current jar location on lambda UI.

How do I find jar location which is in use currently?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Lambda service does not track the location of the package in S3, because once you deploy the version Lambda keeps its own internal copy of the jar file and never looks at S3 again. You could delete the file from S3 after deploying the function and the Lambda service wouldn't care.

If you want to keep backups on S3 you need to manage that yourself. If you want to download the currently deployed Lambda package, you can download the zip file directly from the Lambda service, per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205890/download-an-already-uploaded-lambda-function).